# How to register a created webhook in AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, webhooks, aws-cli

I successfully created a webhook named `webhook1`. But I can't register it.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codepipeline/latest/userguide/pipelines-webhooks-create.html

webhook.json

```
{  
    "webhook":{  
        "name":"webhook1",
        "targetPipeline":"pipeline-1",
        "targetAction":"src",
        "filters":[  
            {  
                "jsonPath":"$.ref",
                "matchEquals":"refs/heads/{Branch}"
            }
        ],
        "authentication":"UNAUTHENTICATED",
        "authenticationConfiguration":{}
    }
}
```

$ aws codepipeline put-webhook --cli-input-json file://webhook.json --region "us-east-2"

```
{
    "webhook": {
        "arn": "arn:aws:codepipeline:us-east-2:12:webhook:webhook1",
        "url": "https://us-east-2.webhooks.aws/trigger?t=ey",
        "definition": {
            "name": "webhook1",
            "filters": [
                {
                    "matchEquals": "refs/heads/{Branch}",
                    "jsonPath": "$.ref"
                }
            ],
            "targetAction": "src",
            "authentication": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
            "targetPipeline": "pipeline-1",
            "authenticationConfiguration": {}
        }
    }
}
```

$ aws codepipeline register-webhook-with-third-party --webhook-name webhook1

```
An error occurred (WebhookNotFoundException) when calling the RegisterWebhookWithThirdParty operation:
```

$ aws codepipeline register-webhook-with-third-party --webhook-name "webhook1"

```
An error occurred (WebhookNotFoundException) when calling the RegisterWebhookWithThirdParty operation:
```

$ aws codepipeline list-webhooks --region us-east-2

```
{
    "webhooks": [
        {
            "definition": {
                "filters": [
                    {
                        "jsonPath": "$.ref",
                        "matchEquals": "refs/heads/{Branch}"
                    }
                ],
                "name": "webhook1",
                "targetPipeline": "pipeline-1",
                "authenticationConfiguration": {},
                "authentication": "UNAUTHENTICATED",
                "targetAction": "src"
            },
            "url": "https://us-east-2.webhooks.aws/trigger?t=ey",
            "arn": "arn:aws:codepipeline:us-east-2:12:webhook:webhook1"
        }
    ]
}
```

With **GITHUB_HMAC** the same issue.

$ aws --version

```
aws-cli/1.15.33 Python/3.5.2 Linux/4.10.0-38-generic botocore/1.10.33
```

Comment: did you find a solution to it? I am still stuck with the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I notice that on your put-webhook and list-webhooks you've included the region in the command: `--region "us-east-2"`.

However, when calling register-webhook-with-third-party you're not passing a region so it's probably defaulting to a different region.

If you include the region in your register-webhook-with-third-party command it'll probably work.